# SimpleMessageContainer can't listen to Message object - Spring RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Dynamic queues and container listeners and my problem is that the method I have to listen to a specific queue won't receive Message objects. I get a ListenerExecutionError exception saying :
"Failed to invoke target method 'dataHandler' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@65f26bf7}]"

My code used to work when I used the RabbitListener annotation and it accepted Message objects perfectly but when using containers I get this problem. I switched the handler argument type from Message to byte[] and the method was called as required. I am guessing there is some converting that the RabbitListener annotation did that I am unaware of doing.

Someone please help me.

This is my Container creation code :

```
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer listen = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        listen.setConnectionFactory(rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
        listen.setQueueNames(testQueue);
        MessageListenerAdapter adapt = new MessageListenerAdapter();
        adapt.setDefaultListenerMethod(randomMethod);
        adapt.setDelegate(this);
        listen.setMessageListener(adapt);
        listen.start();
```

This is my listener method signature.

```
public void randomMethod(Message msg)
```

The line that sends code to this queue is :

```
Message message = new Message(data, props)
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(testQueue, message);
```

Data is a byte array and props is a MessageProperties object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter is not intended for simply passing the message like that, just use a `MessageListener` instead.

```java
listen.setMessageListener(msg -> randomMethod(msg);
```

or...

```java
listen.setMessageListener(this::randomMethod);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just to check, is the adapter for handling types that aren't Message objects like Strings?

Comment: Right, the adapter uses a message converter to convert the message body to the target parameter type, String, domain object, etc.